# Rotativa Issue- Capital letters going out of div after PDFconversion

Tags: rotativa

When I am trying to convert HTML to PDF using Rotativa it works fine for normal text but when I use whole paragraph in Upper Case(As per my need), the text goes out of the border. Attaching image of the issue for better understanding.Please check area in red in image.
Any help,
Image Url-https://i.stack.imgur.com/d76Cl.png
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by adding word-spacing for 1 px in html.